# ModelState validation checking multiple boolean property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, model-validation

I have view model that have multiple boolean properties, in my controller i have checking `ModelState.IsValid` before proceeding to service layer. Now I want to make that `ModelState.IsValid` return `false` if none of boolean property set to true, is there a way to make it happen?

Here is my sample class

```
public class Role {

   public int Id {get; set;}

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a role name")]
   public string Name {get; set;}

   public bool IsCreator {get; set;}

   public bool IsEditor {get; set;}

   public bool IsPublisher {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement your own validation method on the model.  Your model would end up looking something like this:

```
public class Role : IValidatableObject {
   public int Id {get; set;}

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a role name")]
   public string Name {get; set;}

   public bool IsCreator {get; set;}

   public bool IsEditor {get; set;}

   public bool IsPublisher {get; set;}

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
       if (!this.IsCreator && !this.IsEditor && !this.IsPublisher)) {
           yield return new ValidationResult("You must be a creator, editor or publisher");
       }
   }
}
```

Notice how the model:

1. Implements `IValidateableObject`
2. Has a method named `Validate` which returns the type `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>`

During the model binding process this method will automatically be called and if a validation result is returned your `ModelState` will no longer be valid.  So using this familiar code in your controller will make sure you don't take any action unless your custom conditions check out:

```
public class SomeController {
    public ActionResult SomeAction() {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            //Do your stuff!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works but i need to modify your code to `if (!(this.IsCreator || this.IsEditor || this.IsPublisher))`.

Comment: Oops, good catch!  You're right, I flipped my ones and zeroes.

Comment: Hey, i just curious to apply this on client side?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend ValidationAttribute:

```
public class MustBeCreatorEditorPublisherAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    public NoJoeOnMondaysAttribute() { ErrorMessage = "You must be a creator, editor or publisher"; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        using (Role role = value as Role)
        {
            return (role.IsCreator || role.IsEditor || role.IsPublisher);

        }
        return base.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

Your model:

```
[MustBeCreatorEditorPublisher]
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a role name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsCreator { get; set; }

    public bool IsEditor { get; set; }

    public bool IsPublisher { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't need all bool properties to be true if suppose to be like that I have come up with your answer already, instead in my case I want at least 1 of them to be true, thanks for try anyway :)