# client side validation checking multiple boolean property

Tags: javascript, c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class with multiple bool properties that must have at least 1 of that properties to be true,
here is my class

```
public class Role : IValidatableObject {
   public int Id {get; set;}

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a role name")]
   public string Name {get; set;}

   public bool IsCreator {get; set;}

   public bool IsEditor {get; set;}

   public bool IsPublisher {get; set;}

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
       if (!this.IsCreator && !this.IsEditor && !this.IsPublisher)) {
           yield return new ValidationResult("You must be a creator, editor or publisher");
       }
   }
}
```

i have ask this question for server side `ModelState` validation in this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319014/modelstate-validation-checking-multiple-boolean-property), and now i need to do this on client side before my form doing postback..

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? Do you already have a form?

Comment: yes, i have.. i want to trigger validate method like in code sample above on client side.. check my updated sample class

Comment: Your `ValidationAttribute` needs to implement `IClientValidatable`. [Refer this example](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: So this is gonna be complex code.. ok i see if i can accomplish this new attribute..